# Surrounding results of a Find command with quotes

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

So I'm using the following command to get a list of files with their directories surrounded with quotes

```
find /path -type f -mtime -100 -daystart -printf "%f\n" | sed 's/^/"/g' | sed 's/$/"/g' | tr '\n' ' '`
```

But now I want only the file names on there own so I added

```
-printf "%f\n"
```

Giving me

```
find /path -type f -mtime -100 -daystart -printf "%f\n" | sed 's/^/"/g' | sed 's/$/"/g' | tr '\n' ' '`
```

But now the result are no longer surrounded in quotes. I think the printf command is not creating newline for each result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are currently removing the newlines with the `tr` command

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *backtick* at the end of your `find` command indicates that you are redirecting the command output to a variable.  As commented by [hex2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) you are removing the newlines with `tr`.  Even if you weren't piping the results to `tr`, it's possible that your variable wouldn't show newlines unless quoted.

For example,

```
foo=$(find . -type f -mtime -100 -daystart -printf '"%f"\n')
```

would store the results of `find` with pathnames quoted in the variable `foo`.

Doing `echo ${foo}` would not display newlines, while `echo "${foo}"` would.

Comment: This worked for me `-printf '\"%f\"'`, I can get rid of the pipes now

Comment: Just want to add : `%f` for filename only, `%p` for full path (the default) see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215236/301706